# I want to do marquee animation in tailwind and next.js

Tags: css, next.js, tailwind-css

I want to do marquee animation in Tailwind and next.js and some of it I have done. The only issue I am having is that it is not showing one after the other with the first. The second time it will show after some time.

**I want it to be like this:** [image: Want it like this] but it is showing like this [image: Showing like this].

**Here is the code of the tailwind CSS:**

```
  .animate-marquee {
    animation: marquee 10s linear infinite;
    float: left;
  }
```

**Here is the component code:**

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import pathChecking from "../../utils/pathChecking";
import Image from "next/image";

const testimonial_data = [
  {
    desc: "Inform, inspire, connect, and collaborate for meaningful action.",
    id: "0General Partner at Entrepreneur",
  },
  {
    desc: "Addressing the world’s biggest environmental and social challenges.",
    id: "1General Partner at Entrepreneur",
  },
  {
    desc: "Fun, interactive, and immersive technology for real-world positive outcomes. ",
    id: "2General Partner at Entrepreneur",
  },
];

const HeroSliderComponent = () => {
  const route = useRouter();

  return (
    <>
      <div className=" flex animate-marquee space-x-8 w-10000">
        {testimonial_data.map((item, index) => {
          const { id, img, title, desc, name } = item;
          return (
            <div className="text-white" key={id}>
              <div
                className={`relative rounded-2.5xl border border-jacarta-100 bg-white p-12 transition-shadow hover:shadow-xl dark:border-jacarta-700 dark:bg-jacarta-700 `}
              >
                <p className="block font-display text-xl font-medium group-hover:text-accent dark:text-white text-center">
                  {desc}
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default HeroSliderComponent;
```

Infinite marquee with break or delays.

Answer (score 0):

**You can try bellow code:**

```js
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import pathChecking from "../../utils/pathChecking";
import Image from "next/image";

const testimonial_data = [
  {
    desc: "Inform, inspire, connect, and collaborate for meaningful action.",
    id: "0General Partner at Entrepreneur",
  },
  {
    desc: "Addressing the world’s biggest environmental and social challenges.",
    id: "1General Partner at Entrepreneur",
  },
  {
    desc: "Fun, interactive, and immersive technology for real-world positive outcomes. ",
    id: "2General Partner at Entrepreneur",
  },
];

const HeroSliderComponent = () => {
  const route = useRouter();

  return (
    <div className="flex overflow-hidden">
      {[1, 2].map((num) => {
        return (
          <div
            key={num}
            className="min-w-full flex animate-marquee space-x-8 w-10000"
          >
            {testimonial_data.map((item, index) => {
              const { id, img, title, desc, name } = item;
              return (
                <div className="text-white" key={id}>
                  <div
                    className={`relative rounded-2.5xl border border-jacarta-100 bg-white p-12 transition-shadow hover:shadow-xl dark:border-jacarta-700 dark:bg-jacarta-700 `}
                  >
                    <p className="block font-display text-xl font-medium group-hover:text-accent dark:text-white text-center">
                      {desc}
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default HeroSliderComponent;
```